# Angular 7 Service providedIn: 'root'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm very new to angular development so please forgive me if this is a very basic question

But I have a cart service which I have at the moment simply has a simple console log function

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CartService {

  constructor( ) {}
  
  public addItem() {
    console.log('Hello');
  }
}
```

and basically I cannot figure out how to use this service **within a NG Module that I have installed**, I have successfully used it in other components via the constructor but the ngmodule doesn't have this?

I get the fact that it's a singleton at the app-module level by using the providedIn: 'root' tag added in angular 6

but just can't figure out how to call cartService.addItem()?

Thanks if anyone can help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Dependency Injection like this to call the service

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private cartService: CartService) {

  }

  doSomething() {
     this.cartService.addItem();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code of how to use service in component:

Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { yourSeerviceName } from "PATH_TO_SERVICE";
@Component({
    selector: 'app-dummy',
    styleUrls: ['dummy.component.sass'],
    templateUrl: 'dummy.component.html'
})


export class yourComponent implements OnInit {
    // you can provide any name for variable it's upto you
    constructor(private dummyService:yourSeerviceName) {

    }

    //access the method in you'r service by performing below action.
    this.dummyService.yourMethod();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you created a new module, you need to introduce the service to your module, by going to the `.module.ts` file and adding your service to the `providers` array. It will be something like:

```
providers: [
    CartService
  ],
```

Comment: He just asking about how to call the service not register

Comment: Maybe you are right and it wasn't clear for me. The post states, that the OP successfully used that service already in other components, so I wasn't totally sure what the problem was.